# Android service auto restart when stopSelft() with START_STICKY

Tags: android, service, process

I have a Service to push notifications, that must be running in background even when my app is closed or get killed (swipe off from recent apps,...). I use this:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

But I have a BroadcastReceiver too, which will call `stopSelf()` in service class when device is disconnected to network. This receiver works only when I use `return START_NOT_STICKY`, or else the service will automatically restart.

So the question is: How to use `stopSelf()` with `return START_STICKY`? The service must not be restarted when call `stopSelf()`, but will be when main process get killed.

Thanks for reading.

// Edit: I tried to use a separated process for the service, in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<service android:name="com.mypackage.name.MyService"
    android:launchMode="singleTop"
    android:process=":myservice" />
```

and use `START_NOT_STICKY`, but service process still get killed along with main process.

Answer (score 0):

Question 1:

How to use stopSelf() with return START_STICKY?
You can try when you receive your broadcast in your receiver, To restart your service again with return START_NOT_STICKY, Then invoke stopSelf().

Question 2:

If the name assigned to this attribute begins with a colon (':'), a new process, private to the application.
If the process name begins with a lowercase character, the service will run in a global process of that name, provided that it has permission to do so.
So i suggest you change a name android:process="your custom name".